# cambiar style en un menu (html y css)

Tags: html, css

```js
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                                var i;

                                for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
                                  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                                    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                                    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                                      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                                    } else {
                                      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                                    } 
                                  });
                                }
```

```css
.accordion {
          background-color: #eee;
          color: #444;
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 18px;
          width: 80%;
          border: none;
          text-align: left;
          outline: none;
          font-size: 15px;
          transition: 0.4s;
        }

        .active, .accordion:hover {
          background-color: #ccc;
        }

        .accordion:after {
          content: '\002B';
          color: #777;
          font-weight: bold;
          float: right;
          margin-left: 5px;
        }

        .active:after {
          content: "\2212";
        }

        .panel {
          padding: 0 18px;
          background-color: white;
          max-height: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
          color: black;
            max-width: 80%;

        }

         .panel p {
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="general">
                                <button class="accordion">tarifa general</button>
                                <div class="panel">
                                  <p>tratamiento 1  100€</p>
                                  <p>tratamiento 2 500€</p>
                                  <p>tratamiento 3 350€</p>
                                  <p>tratamiento 4 450€</p>
                                </div>

                                <button class="accordion">tarifa jubilados</button>
                                <div class="panel">
                                  <p>tratamiento 1  80€</p>
                                  <p>tratamiento 2 400€</p>
                                  <p>tratamiento 3 300€</p>
                                  <p>tratamiento 4 400€</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

quisiera cambiar y no se como:
-tarifa general y tarifa jubilados poner el texto en negro y alineado verticalmente al centro de su franja gris
-el submenu que aparece con fondo blanco, centrado sobre la franja gris de sus tarifas

gracias de antemano

Comment: En el código expuesto veo que ya sabes como cambiar el color de texto, no hay mas que decir de eso, sobre la alineación vertical, prueba con display flex

Comment: no funciona, el texto aparece blanco y lo necesito negro, el codigo es copiado,  he probado mil cambios pero no los ejecuta

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas modificar la clase acordion que es la clase de los botones. Ya está alienado verticalmente, así que supongo que te referías a una alineación horizontal.

```
.accordion {
          background-color: #eee;
          color: #000;  /* Este es el color del texto */
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 18px;
          width: 80%;
          border: none;
          text-align: left;
          outline: none;
          font-size: 15px;
          transition: 0.4s;
          text-align: center; /* alineación horizontal */
        }
```